# Self Reference Data insertion with Parent and Child Id

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I have a table which is used to add couples. The table schema like below

**MyTable:**

```
Id
Name
SpouseId
```

My aim is to get the spouse details also from the same table using spouseId. Here i can relate the spouseId to Id of same table as self reference.

**Issue:**

From UI, i got object of MyTable which also includes the object of spouse which is also MyTable type.Here when EF inserts the data, 2 entries created and updated the SpouseId of child object as its parentId.

But here i also need to update SpouseId of parent object as child object id.

Any advise on this? or my design is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks funny mate! I would suggest you change the design have a separate table which holds relationships.

Your design might cause problems while inserting as well.

Comment: yes separate table means only spouse detail in the next table.  This is a registration table and i need to treat both person as user equally.

Comment: table : Relationship with columns ID and spouseID

Comment: Here you suggest there is 2 tables. One is MyTable and another is SpouseDetails. Correct? But i have unique GUID in MyTable which is uniquely identify each person. There is no difference in spouse. All are person. But i need to know the spouse relationship in addition to this

Comment: A new table with name Relationship which has two columns ID and spouseID so that you can get access both details.

Comment: please check my previous comment regarding the functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142165/discussion-between-kingsman-and-akhil).